# RDS MYSQL Database Emoji Configuration

Tags: mysql, emoji, amazon-rds

I am working on emoji's to work with mysql database. 
First thing my application uses RDS with version "5.6.22". I used the following link to handle emoji's for RDS mysql DB:

http:/aprogrammers.blogspot.in/2014/12/utf8mb4-character-set-in-amazon-rds.html

As link say's we have to update character set to "utf8mb4" so I did the changes accordingly.

Please find attached image having "Character Set" related variables settings for RDS (RDS-config.JPG).

Still after doing correct configuration, I am getting error saying as follow:
"Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9D\x8C\x86' for column 'column_name' at row 1 ".

Second thing is that when I am working with local mysql DB which has version "5.7.15". I did that same changes with Character set variables for "utf8mb4". For details please check attached image (Local-config.JPG).

Now if I connect to local DB, emoji works fine.

I can anyone help me out with this issue.
Thanks in advance. 
Harshvardhan Pawar

RDS Config details:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGOZ6.jpg)

Local Config details:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXkOc.jpg)

Comment: Correction: link used for implemention http://aprogrammers.blogspot.in/2014/12/utf8mb4-character-set-in-amazon-rds.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had very similar issue. The problem was that I set `utf8mb4` for Parameter Group which was not selected as default group of my RDS instance.